# Store shiny inputs from DT in a data.frame

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I want to store user inputs in shinyapp from DT in a data.frame. Here is what I have achieved by far.

```
library(shiny)
library(data.table)
library(DT)
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    title = 'Radio buttons in a table',
    DT::dataTableOutput('foo'),
    verbatimTextOutput('sel'), verbatimTextOutput('x2')

  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {

    x <- data.table( 'Breed Split' = paste0("F",rep(0:16)), Frisian = rep(1,17), Cross = rep(2,17), Jersey = rep(3,17) ,
                     checked=c(rep("Frisian",9),rep("Cross",5),rep("Jersey",3))
    )

    x[, Frisian := sprintf( '<input type="radio" name="%s" value="%s" %s/>', `Breed Split`, x[, Frisian],ifelse("Frisian"==x[, checked],"checked" ,""))]
    x[, Cross := sprintf( '<input type="radio" name="%s" value="%s" %s/>', `Breed Split`, x[, Cross],ifelse("Cross"==x[, checked],"checked" ,"" ))]
    x[, Jersey := sprintf( '<input type="radio" name="%s" value="%s" %s/>', `Breed Split`, x[, Jersey] ,ifelse("Jersey"==x[, checked],"checked" ,""))]

    output$foo = DT::renderDataTable(
      x[,-c("checked")], escape = FALSE, selection = 'none', server = FALSE, rownames=FALSE,
      options = list(dom = 't', paging = FALSE, ordering = FALSE),
      callback = JS("table.rows().every(function(i, tab, row) {
                    var $this = $(this.node());
                    $this.attr('id', this.data()[0]);
                    $this.addClass('shiny-input-radiogroup');
  });
                    Shiny.unbindAll(table.table().node());
                    Shiny.bindAll(table.table().node());")
    )

    inputs <- reactive ({ str(sapply(x$`Breed Split`, function(i) input[[i]])) })
    output$sel = renderPrint({ sapply(x$`Breed Split`, function(i) input[[i]]) })

  }
)
```

What I want to achieve is the user input results in a data.frame like the following:

```
sel <- data.frame(id = paste0("F",rep(0:16)), input = c(rep(1,9), rep(2,5), rep(3,3) ))
```

**WORKAROUND**

I found the following workaround for the problem. It is working as desired, but I am getting a warning message though.

```
output$sel <- renderTable({ 
      temp <- unlist(lapply(x$Breed, function(i) input[[i]]))
      sel <<- data.frame(id = paste0("F",rep(0:16)), input = as.numeric(temp) )
      return(sel)
    })

##
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:5651
Warning: Error in data.frame: arguments imply differing number of rows: 17, 0
Stack trace (innermost first):
    80: data.frame
    79: renderTable [E:\R_workspace/app.R#36]
    78: func
    77: origRenderFunc
    76: output$sel
     1: runApp
```

Comment: i am not getting a warning message running your workaround,...can you share that? A while ago i wrote an app that logs all input values without having to specify them. Maybe thats also of interest for you: https://github.com/Timag/ShinyInputLog/blob/master/app.R

Comment: You app is very helpful, thanks for sharing that. I have added the warning message under the workaround.